# How to use regex to validate a text box in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, regex

This question seems to be duplicated to someone but it's not. The script was working perfectly fine, till this morning but it acts kind of weird right now. I have tried many suggested ways to change the code like remove the else part and check the condition with if!= "true" but no luck.

**jquery**

```
$("#controlButton").click(function () {

    var SHPname = $("#fname").val();
    var textfieldmask = /^[a-z\.\s-]{2,}$/;
    /// check full name 
    if (SHPname.length > 0) {
        var testname = textfieldmask.test(SHPname);
        alert(testname);
        if (testname == "true") {
            var tstnm = "ok";
            alert(tstnm);
        } else {
            alert("Enter the full name!");
            $('#fname').focus();
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        alert("Please enter the name");
        $('#fname').focus();
        return true;
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<label class="required" for="name" title="Enter your name">
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" />Reciver's name</label>
<label for="formsubmit" class="nocontent">
    <a id="controlButton" href="#" class="progress-button">
        <p id="BTNtxt">Save</p>
        <img id="loadergif" src="../images/loader-cat.gif" width="30" height="14"  alt=""/>
    </a>
    <strong>Note:</strong> 
    Items marked 
    <img src="images/required.gif" alt="Required marker" width="12" height="12" /> 
    are required fields
</label>
```

the weird part is that, I have the first alert "true" but the code runs !="true" and alerts Enter the full name!
Why is that happening?  Please help me out here.

Comment: Your code runs as soon as the page loads. Add it inside a function and then call it with an onClick. Or was that intentionally?

Comment: @Geo I have missed 1 line of code, it's inside   $("#controlButton").click(function() {
}) function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. Is working in jsFiddle. Keep the `testname == true` but without the `""`

```
 $("#controlButton").click(function () {

     var SHPname = $("#fname").val();
     var textfieldmask = /^[a-z\.\s-]{2,}$/;
     /// check full name 
     if (SHPname.length > 0) {
         var testname = textfieldmask.test(SHPname);
         alert(testname);
         if (testname == true) {
             var tstnm = "ok";
             alert(tstnm);
         } else {
             alert("Enter the full name!");
             $('#fname').focus();
            // return false;  Do you get this return anywhere somehow? if not you don't need it
         }
     } else {
         alert("Please enter the name");
         $('#fname').focus();
         //return true; Same here
     }
 });
```

Comment: YAY!  its working the problem was in "" as you mentioned, You are just wonderful. appreciated really,

Comment: where is that extra piece of code? I can only see you checking for `$("#fname").val();` here. can you update your post with everything?

Comment: No problem bud. I upvoted you but don't ask for upvotes in here because you may end up getting a down vote instead :) weird crowd that is :P

Comment: thanks yes they did down voted actually :) but never mind thanks for the help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Here, using testname you are performing, [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

> The test() method executes a search for a match between a regular expression and a specified string. Returns true or false.

And in your snippet you are comparing `true === "true"`. This always fails. So you should be using `if (testname === true )` or  `if (testname)` ( as its boolean )

Answer (score 0):

here is working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akhildave/Ry64u/)

HTML:

```
<label class="required" for="name" title="Enter your name">
 <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" />Reciver's name</label>
 <label for="formsubmit" class="nocontent">
  <a id="controlButton" href="#" class="progress-button">
    <p id="BTNtxt">Save</p>
    <img id="loadergif" src="../images/loader-cat.gif" width="30" height="14"  alt=""/>
  </a>
  <strong>Note:</strong> 
     Items marked 
    <img src="images/required.gif" alt="Required marker" width="12" height="12" /> 
    are required fields
  </label>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
  $("#controlButton").click(function() {

   var SHPname = $("#fname").val();
   var textfieldmask =  /^[a-z\.\s-]{2,}$/;
    /// check full name 
       if (SHPname.length > 0){
            var testname = textfieldmask.test(SHPname);
     alert (testname);
               if (testname == true ){
                  var tstnm = "ok";
      alert (tstnm);
               } else {
                  alert ("Enter the full name!");
      $('#fname').focus();  
                 return false;
              }       
            } else {
    alert ("Please enter the name");
     $('#fname').focus();  
                 return true;
        }  
  });
```

**UPDATED:**
here is your fiddle updated to validate both textboxes   [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akhildave/Ry64u/2/)

Comment: Thanks Dave, appreciated

Comment: I did, but someone down voted you, I think it's wrong to let people down vote and up vote each other, cause some people aren't behaving properly. >: